# Android JsonParsing Suggestion

Tags: android, json, listview, fragment

I'm interested in a way to parse JSON only once, and somehow save it in the listview.
Ex: When the user goes to the same fragment again JSON doesn't load the list, the fragment shows the list loaded previously.

If you can be so kind and help me with a suggestion or a link to an article, if this thing I'm asking for is possible.  BTW, I know how to parse, and put the JSON into listview; I'm not asking for a way to do this. I have a problem (maybe not so of a problem) every time user goes to same fragment: data is loading again and again.

Comment: i'm sorry can you at least explain why did you put the - before putting it ?

Comment: too broad: it can be retain-ready fragment(or parent activity), iternal storage(db, sharedprefs, simple file with saved response) ... you can use some http client library with caching, etc, etc ... it depends on your needs

Comment: i'm sorry , thank you for youre response, wich would be faster , in app, sharedprefs or , http client library with catching(or the library must be from the rest api side) ?

Comment: faster will be storing already parsed objects but it can be "killed" early(fx if app goes temporary into background and OS decide to kill it) ... you can also mix client file cache/db + some memory cache (some singleton class with data)

Comment: i need to load the data from json in a fragment only once , then the app is opened,and if the user goes back to the fragment the data will not load because it stayed there

Comment: Sir thank you a lot , you gave me some much material to think of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse JSON into Java objects, then save those objects in SQLite database so your app can retrieve it to repopulate your Listview at any point. Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) on how to set it up.

Comment: this is indeed good , but , i must repopulate the lv with the valid information , there might be or not more orders, or messages,and if i save it in db it will lost some messages

Comment: So just update the database when your data chenges. You can set up a Service to do that.

Comment: i think i will stick up with youre idea thank you , btw, is the proces of loading from db fast ?

Comment: Since all storage in mobile devices is flash storage, reading from a database is as fast as reading from RAM. If this has helped you please consider accepting the answer. Thanks.